# VueJS use v-for after mounted or else method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i need to get array after mounted was done, for create child of section in html.
Like - getting objects from api -> return array with objects -> create child blocks.

```
mounted() {
apiLoop.then((result) => {
    let tracksArray = result.data
      for (let i = 0; i < tracksArray.length; i++) {
        let genSection = document.querySelector('.charts')
        genSection.appendTo(`<div class="container card chartsCard" data-musicid="${tracksArray[i].id}">)
      }
})}
```

But how to make it right? Use v-for (but how to send tracksArray to v-for?) or create element in mounted?

Comment: Why you are creating childs DOM in the mounted ? You can directly do that in template inside v-for loop. Kindly check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tn8uadj1/ and let me know the exact requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a variable in data like this example:

```
data() {
  return {
    items: [{ message: 'Foo' }, { message: 'Bar' }]
  }
}
```

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in items">
  {{ parentMessage }} - {{ index }} - {{ item.message }}
</li>
```

[List Rendering](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for)